# How to output 3 things on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm changing a WordPress theme. The theme has highlighted entries you can add in the admin panel. I can enter a title, the normal description, and at bottom I can put a specific excerpt.

The problem is that i must have a title, a subtitle, and the description, for these objects at home.

If i use excerpts(), with the input of excerpts empty, the excerpts function takes X words of the description. If i wrote a subtitle in the excerpts input, it only shows those words, not the description of the entry.

Is there a way to have 3 things in an entry of WordPress, or to show the description like excerpts with a limit of words?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
     <div class="home-sectors-title">
            <h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
     </div>
     <div class=""home-sectors-subtitle">
            <?php echo excerpt('17'); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="home-sectors-description">
            //description here
     </div>
```

- Title of the entry (like normal post)
- A short subtitle
- The long text of the entry (html text like normal post )

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code segments

Comment: Could you make your question clearer please?

Comment: Please update your question too

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but you have an extra " in class=""home-sectors-subtitle"

Answer (score 1):

You could create a child theme, copy the required file and edit the code there. In this case I presume you would want to delete/comment the description section?

Using a Child Theme: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Child theme plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-click-child-theme/

Comment: Dont have time to do that, there isnt a function to show the text you enter in one entry?

Comment: Yes, clear up your question. I have no idea what you are trying to do.